# Google maps infowindow display kml object name and link

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, kml

I have some working code to display a KML layer on Google maps. When you click on the various parts of the layer their respective name pops up in an info window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
// Load Google Maps API
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXX&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">



function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.875696, -0.624207);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://XXXXXXX.org/gliding/grid3.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: false,
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
    showInContentWindow(text);
  });

  function showInContentWindow(text) {
    var sidediv = document.getElementById('content-window');
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%; float:left"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like the info window to also contain a link to a page with the same name as object clicked on. For example if the user clicks on a shape in the KML layer called Tom the info window says Tom Click Here. If the user clicks the link they are taken to www.XYZ.com/Tom.

I'm sure this is quite simple, but I'm new to javascript and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a hack than a solution (which means google could change a property name and this would stop working.

However, here you go

```
google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
    kmlEvent.featureData.infoWindowHtml += '<a href="' + kmlLayer.url + '">Click Here</a>';
    showInContentWindow(text);
});
```